# Swift 4 Post Request to ASP.NET HttpGet Method

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, swift

I am trying to call an ASP.NET Entity Framework HttpGet Method:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public BookingLCPreview MarkAsAttended(string asAttended)
        {
            BookingLCPreview existing = db.Data.FirstOrDefault(u => u.qrCode == asAttended);
            existing.attendedPreview = true;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return existing;
        }
```

From my swift 4 app like so:

```
func markAsAttended(jsonData: String) {

        if !jsonData.isEmpty {

            let url = URL(string: webservice + "BookingLCPreviewsAPI")!

            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            let postString = "asAttended=" + jsonData
            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

            URLSession.shared.getAllTasks { (openTasks: [URLSessionTask]) in
                print(openTasks)
            }

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (responseData: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
                print(response!)
            })
            task.resume()
        }

    }
```

But its not working, all this call does is post a new item to my db, when I want it to call MarkAsAttended and update an item in my db, When I call the URL in my browser it does as expected....updates a record, but on my app it adds an new item. What am I doing wrong? I tried changed HttpGet to HttpPost but that didnt work :(

Here is my route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: As per your ASP.NET Code the method is Get
And You are calling in swift is Post
So Change it to request.httpMethod = "GET"

Comment: I tried that, openTasks is empty and I get an error when printing the respoinse...` Task <8BEF9BFC-44CA-4C7A-BB53-EB6647C1CFF2>.<1> finished with error - code: -1001`

Comment: Did you check in postman?

Comment: How do I do that?